# mktime(&time_check) returns "-1" only

Tags: c++, time

So my Code is basicly this:

```
    #include <time.h>

    struct tm time_check;
    time_check.tm_year = 2018;
    time_check.tm_mon  = 03;
    time_check.tm_mday = 28;

    if(mktime(&time_check) != -1)
```

the condition is false everytime, but why?, the date is correct isn´t it?

Comment: Is the rest of the structure properly zeroed out or not? Did you check `errno` for more specifics?

Comment: @tadman Should be, how do I check errno?

Comment: `#include <errno.h>` and then... check the `errno` thread local variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to initialize the tm structure and the year must be subtracted 1900.
Try this code:

```
    struct tm time_check;
time_t now;
time( &now );
localtime_s( &time_check, &now );
time_check.tm_year = 2018-1900;
time_check.tm_mon = 03;
time_check.tm_mday = 28;
if( mktime( &time_check ) != -1 )
```

Comment: Another option is to initialize the struct with: `struct tm time_check = {}`

Comment: so for everyone who is interested, it was the subtraction of 1900 and zero out the construct, thanks for everyone!!